# check database connection after button is click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building a website that has a reservation. I use ajax to send information from forms into the another page which insert the information into my database. To make it even useful, I want to make a test connection into my database. After a user fills up all the fields required he will click the submit button and a test connection must check first before sending the data. And when the connection fails, it will tell the user that the connection is not set(maybe his internet connection is lost, or the server itself is failing). In that way, the website prevents prompting the user that their reservation data is sent, but actually NOT.

EDITED:

Here's my running and fixed code:

```
$("#esubmit2").click(function(){
    var event2 = document.getElementsByName("eevent2")[0].value;
    var engager2 = document.getElementsByName("eengager2")[0].value;
    var contact2 = document.getElementsByName("econtact2")[0].value;
    var eadd2 = document.getElementsByName("eeadd2")[0].value;
    var venue2 = document.getElementsByName("evenue2")[0].value;
    var datein2 = document.getElementsByName("edatein2")[0].value;
    var message2 = document.getElementsByName("emessage2")[0].value;
    var reg2 = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if(event2 == "" || event2 == " "){
        $("#eevent2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(engager2 == "" || engager2 == " "){
        $("#eengager2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(contact2 == "" || contact2 == " "){
        $("#econtact2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(venue2 == "Venue:"){
        $("#evenue2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(datein2 == "" || datein2 == " "){
        $("#edatein2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(message2 == "" || datein2 == " "){
        $("#emessage2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(eadd2 != ""){
        if(reg2.test(eadd2) == false){
            $("#eeadd2").focus();
            $("#eeadd2").css("backgroundColor","#800517");
            $("#eeadd2").css("color","#FFFFFF");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            sendreserve_event2(); // call function sendreserve()
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        sendreserve_event2(); // call function sendreserve()
        return false;
    }
})


function sendreserve_event2(){ // send informations to database
    var data_string = $("form#eform2").serialize(); // IMPORTANT

    $.ajax({
        type:       "POST",
        url:        "submitreserve_eventpc.php",
        data:       data_string,
        success:    function(json) {

        if(json == 1){
            $("#eevent2").val("");
            $("#eengager2").val("");
            $("#econtact2").val("");
            $("#eeadd2").val("");
            $("#evenue2").val("Venue:");
            $("#edatein2").val("");
            $("#emessage2").val("");

            $("#eeadd2").css("backgroundColor","#FFFFFF");
            $("#eeadd2").css("color","#555");

            alert("Reservation Successful!!! \n\nPlease wait for your reservation code to be send to your e-mail account or contact number.\n\nThank you!");

            return false;
        }
        else{
            alert("Sorry for the inconvenience but the connection to our database failed.\nPlease check you internet connection or refresh you page.\n\nIf one of the above failed please report to our admin.\nThank You.");
            return false;
        }


        }//end success function


    }); //end ajax call
    return false; // IMPORTANT
}
```

submitreserve_eventpc.php:

```
if($test){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblevent(eventName,engager,contactNumber,emailAdd,venue,checkinDate,message) VALUES('$event2','$engager2','$contact2','$eadd2','$venue2','$datein2','$message2')");
    $ok = 1;
}
else{
    $ok = 0;
}

echo json_encode($ok);
```

If there's any improvement that you see please edit. For now this met my needs :)

Comment: Thats wonderful, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: submitreserve_eventpc.php should check if the database connection is valid before submitting the data, if it isn't it should return data to your AJAX function, the AJAX function should have validation in the success message depending on whether or not your PHP submitted the data or failed database connection.

Comment: @Darren, can I check database connection using javascript? Since, some of validation falls there.

Comment: @Matt, how can I pass data that was sent to submitreserve_eventpc.php back to AJAX script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this.

Your php.file

```
 <?php
   $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
   if($con){
    // do insertion  data here into the database
    $sql = "Insert into table query";
    if($sql){
     echo "Data inserted successfully";
    }else{
     echo "Sorry! some error occured ".mysql_error(); 
    }
   }else{
    echo "Unable to connect to the server";
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you want me to put that code on the top of my submitreserve_eventpc.php. In that case, the user can't still be prompted by the website since it doesn't redirect on that page, but falls here:  $.ajax({success:    function() { alert("something went wrong"); }});

Please correct me if I'm wrong....

Comment: The above code has to be put in a file where you are sending the ajax call to submit the data for the insertion. Then you first check for the connection. if connection fail, you send the message "Unable t connect to the server". And if the connection is done, then you connect with the database and after connection is done to data base, you fire your SQL query to insert value. If ever thing goes right, you display message "Data inserted successfully". otherwise you output somthing went wrong while insertion

Comment: @Darren and Sandeep Pal, Thanks for response. I've tried it anyway. I change the connection password to my not real password for a test. It must detect that a connection is failed. But as I guess, it still prompt me that my data is sent, but actually NOT.

Comment: I guess we aren't understand each other. hehe. Are you trying to tell me that a button after clicked is first direct to a page that contains test connection then after it was successful it will fire my ajax code and validate again some data and directs me into another page again where insertion must be executed???

Comment: See Alexdn, what i meant here is, when you click "button", fir you validate all your data. Then you send ajax call to the php page. In php file, you first check for "Mysql Connection" and if connection is failed, you return "connection failed message". And if your connection is proper, then you run your insetion query and return message "Whether successfull" or "Not successful". whatever msg you echo in php file get's return as response to ajax call. then u check for msg in ajax call. if your response is "Unable to connection to database", u alert msg else u alert for "Data insertion message".

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
function sendreserve_event2(){ // send informations to database
    var data_string = $("form#eform2").serialize(); // IMPORTANT

    $.ajax({
        type:       "POST",
        url:        "submitreserve_eventpc.php",
        data:       data_string
    }).done(function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        message = data.message;

        if (message == "success")
        {
            $("#eevent2").val("");
            $("#eengager2").val("");
            $("#econtact2").val("");
            $("#eeadd2").val("");
            $("#evenue2").val("Venue:");
            $("#edatein2").val("");
            $("#emessage2").text("");

            $("#eeadd2").css("backgroundColor","#FFFFFF");
            $("#eeadd2").css("color","#555");

            $("#esubmit2").blur();
            alert("Reservation Successful!!! \n\nPlease wait for your reservation code to be send to your e-mail account or contact number.\n\nThank you!");

        } else {
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
    return false; // IMPORTANT
}
```

In your PHP file could be changed to what is below.

```
$myDatabase = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$myDatabase) 
{
    $message = 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error();
} else {
    $event2   = $_POST['eevent2'];
    $engager2 = $_POST['eengager2'];
    $contact2 = $_POST['econtact2'];
    $eadd2    = $_POST['eeadd2'];
    $venue2   = $_POST['evenue2'];
    $datein2  = $_POST['edatein2'];
    $message2 = $_POST['emessage2'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblevent(eventName,engager,contactNumber,emailAdd,venue,checkinDate,message) VALUES('$event2','$engager2','$contact2','$eadd2','$venue2','$datein2','$message‌​2')");
    $message = 'success';
}

$response = array('message' => $message);
echo json_encode($response); // This is the data that your AJAX function gets in .done
```

Comment: here's my PHP code:

<?php

$event2 = $_POST['eevent2'];
$engager2 = $_POST['eengager2'];
$contact2 = $_POST['econtact2'];
$eadd2 = $_POST['eeadd2'];
$venue2 = $_POST['evenue2'];
$datein2 = $_POST['edatein2'];
$message2 = $_POST['emessage2'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblevent(eventName,engager,contactNumber,emailAdd,venue,checkinDate,message) VALUES('$event2','$engager2','$contact2','$eadd2','$venue2','$datein2','$message2')");

?>

Comment: Please edit your original answer to put it there so it's formatted properly :3

Comment: @Alexdn I have updated the PHP portion of my code to match yours. This will pass back a message to the AJAX function, either being success or the mysql error.

Comment: Dont work for me :( When I click the button it doesn't alert me whether it successful or not.