# Simple passing of value of a variable from PHP file to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass value of a variable from PHP file to use it as an argument into JavaScript function. E.g:

PHP:

```
$passed = "passed";
$failed = "failed";

$name = $_POST['name'];

if($name == "lekz"){
     echo $passed; // this variable will pass to js file
}
else{
    echo $failed; // this variable will pass to js file
}
```

JS:

```
function trace(){

    var con = "passed"

    if($passed == con){
        alert("passed");
    }
    else{
        alert("failed");
    }
}
```

In what way can I pass variables from PHP into JS function?

Comment: Is the JS function in the PHP file?

Comment: Nope. A separate file sir.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to use the AJAX method in the linked question.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to do an AJAX request. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Barmar, actually sir I've been troubled from my past question so I believe I can find it easier to ask a new question. BTW here's my past question sir maybe you can help me into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008625/check-database-connection-after-button-is-click

Comment: Looks like you already have good answers there. If you're having trouble understanding them, you need to study how AJAX works. SO is not a substitute for learning how to program.

Comment: I guess so sir. Maybe I'm just so stressed and have to take a break :) Thank you btw :D